# Why does Collections.sort() apply only for lists and not for sets?

Tags: java, list, collections, set

Why does `Collections.sort()` apply only for `List`s and not for `Set`s? Is there any particular reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most (but **not all**) `Set` implementations do not have a concept of order, so `Collections.sort` does not support them as a whole. If you want a set with a concept of order, you can use something like a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> A [`NavigableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) implementation based on a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). The elements are ordered using their [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or by a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Or a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the `Set` interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from `HashSe`t in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (*insertion-order*)

Answer (score 9):

A Set, by definition, has no order.

Comment: It may be more appropriate to say that a set does not necessarily have an order. There are types of sets that do have orders (for example, TreeSet)

Comment: This statement is not accurate, not all `Set`s are orderless. `Set`s are simply specified as collections that do not contain duplicates.

Comment: @arshajii in the mathematical sense, a set has no order.  I think that was faffaffaff's point

Comment: @AlexBrooks Yes, but that's not relevant in this context. A *mathematical* set might be defined differently than a Java set.

Answer (score 5):

A `Set` is not a `List`. While a `List`, by contract, is supposed to retain insertion order (otherwise, methods such as `.get(someindex)` would not make any sense), this is not the case for a `Set`. You have no method to get an element at a particular index in a `Set`! Neither do you have methods to insert at a particular position etc.

More specifically, the ordering of `Set` is undefined; however, *implementations* of `Set` can add ordering constraints.

For instance:

- `LinkedHashSet` retains insertion ordering;
- `TreeSet` maintains natural ordering of its elements, either because its elements implement `Comparable`, or because you supply a `Comparator`.

If you sorted a `LinkedHashSet`, you would break its insertion ordering guarantee!

Answer (score 1):

A set is not ordered. You can use [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). Or you can create a List from the set and sort it.

Comment: Natural ordering is not the only available ordering, see `LinkedHashSet`

Answer (score 0):

List is an ordered set of elements while Set is not which implies that none of Set elements will have any sequence number. So you can't sort it.